# How to plot time as moving backwards as you move up the y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a waterfall plot using matplotlib's pcolormesh. I want to have frequency on the x axis, time on the y axis, and intensity as the color of each pixel. Right now, I have the following:

```
plt.pcolormesh(freqs, time, intensities)
plt.show()
```

Is there any way for me to change this so that time 0 is at the top of the y axis and the last time (in this case 200 seconds) is at the bottom? This way, as you look at the plot from top to bottom, time is increasing.

Note that simply reversing the list does not result in the proper plot. For example:
    x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    plt.plot(x,y)

This does not result in a plot where moving up the y axis takes you from 5 to 0.

Comment: yes @PadraicCunningham

Comment: can you not just reverse the list?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This doesn't work. Look at, for example,     x = [5,4,3,2,1]
y = [5,4,3,2,1]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

Comment: `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Is there a way to just change the y axis?

Comment: try command above, I corrected it

Comment: No worries, you're welcome, I will add it as answer to close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invert the `y` axis use `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` or `plt.gca().invert_xaxis()` for the `x` axis.